# Scalable Node Express Routes

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I want to set up routes in Node Express to be scalable.

I understand how to set up working routes...it's the failures / mismatches I'm struggling with. More specifically, I am struggling with how to handle 404 errors.

Here is what I have...

```
app.get('/:folder',function(req,res) {
    var path = 'site/' + req.params.folder + '/index.jade';
    res.render(path);
});

app.get('/:folder/:topic',function(req,res) {
    var path = 'site/' + req.params.folder + '/' + req.params.topic;
    res.render(path);
});

app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.status(404).render('site/404.jade');
});
```

The challenge is, :folder and :topic will match to anything so the 404 will never fire. I do not want to hard code all our folder and topic names. So, how do I set up my routing so requests will fall through to the 404 should a folder / topic not exist?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Final, working solution is as follows. Thanks, everyone.

```
var fs = require('fs');

app.get('/:folder',function(req,res,next) {
    var path = __dirname + '/views/site/' + req.params.folder + '/index.jade';

    if(fs.existsSync(path))
    {
        res.render(path);
    }
    else
    {
        next();
    }
});

app.get('/:folder/:topic',function(req,res,next) {
    var path = __dirname + '/views/site/' + req.params.folder + '/' + req.params.topic + '.jade';

    if(fs.existsSync(path))
    {
        res.render(path);
    }
    else
    {
        next();
    }
});

app.use(function(req, res){
    res.status(404).render('site/404.jade');
});
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone for their suggestions.

Answer (score 5):

There's a third (optional) parameter passed to `app.get`: `next`. `next` is actually a callback that you can call to cause your route to fall through to the next one.

So, you can do something like this:

```
app.get('/:folder',function(req, res, next) {
    var path = 'site/' + req.params.folder + '/index.jade';
    var pathIsValid = ...  // use something like fs.exists to check if the path is valid
    if (pathIsValid) {
        res.render(path);
    } else {
        next()
    }
});
```

If next is called, it'll try the next route. If that (and any others) calls next, then you'll get to your 404 handler.

Answer (score 2):

In your folder and topic routes, you need to use `fs.exists` to see if the view path exists, and if not, just call `next()` without rendering anything. Then the routing will proceed to the 404 handler.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
app.get('/:folder/:topic',function(req,res) {
    var path = 'site/' + req.params.folder + '/' + req.params.topic;
    if(fileExists(path)) {
      res.render(path);
    } else {
      res.status(404).render('site/404.jade');        
    }
});

app.get('/:folder',function(req,res) {
    var path = 'site/' + req.params.folder + '/index.jade';
    if(fileExists(path)) {
      res.render(path);
    } else {
      res.status(404).render('site/404.jade');        
    }
});


app.all('*', function(req, res){
    res.status(404).render('site/404.jade');
});
```

if we has url like `/folder/topic`, it satisfies route 1, and request is processed.
if we has `/folder` url, it fails to satisfy route 1, but satisfies route 2.
if we has something different, than we render path 3.

`fileExists` is some function to verify, that template exists, http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_existssync_path for example